# Don't you think this is ugly? How do I fix switch ugly JS statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is so ugly and how do I organize this switch statement?

```
function renderDataTypeIcon(dataType: string) {
  let iconName; 
  switch (dataType) {
    case "STRING": //TO-DO => ENUM
      iconName = "text";
      break;
    case "NUMBER":
      iconName = "number_input";
      break; 
    case "ARRAY":
      iconName = "standard_objects";
      break; 
    case "DATE":
      iconName = "dayview";
      break; 
    case "OBJECT":
      iconName = "standard_objects";
      break; 
    case "INTEGER":
      iconName = "number_input";
      break;
    case "BOOLEAN":
      iconName = "radio_button";
      break;
    default:
      iconName = "warning"
  }
```

Comment: This would be better on Code Review:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an object

```
const dataTypeIcons: { [key: string]: string } = {
  STRING: 'text',
  NUMBER: 'number_input',
  etc
}

and use

const icon = dataTypeIcons[dataType] || 'warning';
```

Comment: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ STRING: string; NUMBER: string; ARRAY: string; DATE: string; OBJECT: string; INTEGER: string; BOOLEAN: string; }'.`

Comment: Use the type `{ [key: string]: string }` I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It may be cleaner just to use an object to map the datatypes to icons:

```js
const DATATYPE_TO_ICON: {[key: string]: string} = {
    "STRING":  "text",
    "NUMBER": "number_input",
    "ARRAY": "standard_objects",
    "DATE": "dayview",
    "OBJECT": "standard_objects",
    "INTEGER": "number_input",
    "BOOLEAN": "radio_button",
}

function renderDataTypeIcon(dataType: string) {
    return DATATYPE_TO_ICON[dataType] || "warning";
}
```

Comment: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ STRING: string; NUMBER: string; ARRAY: string; DATE: string; OBJECT: string; INTEGER: string; BOOLEAN: string; }'.ts(7053)

Comment: I updated my answer to specify a type for the `DATATYPE_TO_ICON` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate the temporary variable `iconName` and all the `break` statements if you just `return` the matched string.

```js
function renderDataTypeIcon(dataType: string) {
  switch (dataType) {
    case "STRING": return "text";
    case "NUMBER": return "number_input";
    case "ARRAY": return "standard_objects"; 
    case "DATE": return "dayview";
    case "OBJECT": return "standard_objects";
    case "INTEGER": return "number_input";
    case "BOOLEAN": return "radio_button";
    default: return "warning";
  }
}
```